# PHP: Uncaught Error Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a simple section in which I am displaying data from the database,

If the user clicks eg construction and selects eg Algeria, I am displaying `[251, 211,712]` if a user clicks eg Power and selects eg. Egypt I am displaying `[406, 228,559]` etc

Now I want if the user clicks the button `All available industries` and select eg. Algeria I want to display this `[251+203+130, 211,712+179,877+154,946]` in a simple way like this in SQL

```
SELECT sum(SumofNoOfProjects) as sum_projects, sum(SumofTotalBudgetValue) as sum_value FROM `meed` WHERE Countries = 'Algeria'
```

Which give me this `[611, 546535]`

Here is my solution

HTML

```
<div id="interactive-layers">
    <div buttonid="43" class="video-btns">
        <span class="label">Construction</span></div>
    <div buttonid="44" class="video-btns">
        <span class="label">Power</span></div>
    <div buttonid="45" class="video-btns">
        <span class="label">Oil</span></div>
    <div buttonid="103" class="video-btns">
        <span class="label">All available industries</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is js ajax

```
$("#interactive-layers").on("click", ".video-btns", function(){
    if( $(e.target).find("span.label").html()=="Confirm" ) {

        var selectedCountries = [];

        $('.video-btns .selected').each(function () {
            selectedCountries.push( $(this).parent().find("span.label").html() ) ;
        });

        if( selectedCountries.length>0 ) {
            if(selectedCountries.indexOf("All available countries")>-1) {
                selectedCountries = [];
            }


        } else {

            return;
        }

        var ajaxurl = "";
        if(selectedCountries.length>0) {
            ajaxurl = "data.php";
        } else {
            ajaxurl = "dataall.php";

        }

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                    countries: selectedCountries.join(","),
                    sector: selectedSector
            },
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
                result = JSON.parse(result);
                $(".video-btns").each(function () {
                    var getBtn = $(this).attr('buttonid');
                    if (getBtn == 106) {
                        var totalProjects = $("<span class='totalprojects'>"+ result[0] + "</span>");
                        $(this).append(totalProjects)
                    }else if(getBtn ==107){
                        var resultBudget = result[1]
                        var totalBudgets = $("<span class='totalbudget'>"+ '&#36m' +" " + resultBudget +"</span>");
                        $(this).append( totalBudgets)
                    }
                });
                return;
              }
        });
    }
});
```

**UPDATE** Here is Updated  data.php

```
      <?php

$selectedSectorByUser = $_POST['sector'];
$countries = explode(",", $_POST['countries']);
echo '$countries';

 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "meedadb");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())   {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

 $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM meed");
 $data = array();

 $wynik = [];
$totalProjects = 0;
$totalBudget = 0;

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
    if($row['Sector']==$selectedSectorByUser && in_array($row['Countries'],$countries ) ) {

     $totalProjects+= $row['SumofNoOfProjects'];
     $totalBudget+= $row['SumofTotalBudgetValue'];

    }elseif($selectedSectorByUser =="All available industries"){
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, 
      "SELECT sum(SumofNoOfProjects) as 'SumofNoOfProjects, sum(SumofTotalBudgetValue) as SumofTotalBudgetValue 
      FROM `meed` 
      WHERE Countries = '$countries'");

      while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
         echo json_encode([ $row['SumofNoOfProjects,'], $row['SumofTotalBudgetValue '] ] );
         exit;
        }

      exit;
    }
 }

 echo json_encode([ $totalProjects, $totalBudget ] );
exit();
?>
```

Now when the user clicks `All available industries` btn and selects a country I  get the following error

> b>Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\custom-xammp\htdocs\editor\data.php:23

What do I need to change to get what I want? any help or suggestion will be appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you  should fecth a row (at least)

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno())   {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$result = mysqli_query($conn, 
    "SELECT sum(SumofNoOfProjects) as sum_projects, sum(SumofTotalBudgetValue) as sum_value 
    FROM `meed` 
    WHERE Countries = '$countries'");

while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);) {
 echo json_encode([ $row['sum_projects'], $row['sum_value'] ] );
 exit;
}
```

for the multiple countries

Asuming you  `$_POST['countries']` contains `"'Egypt','Algerie'"` 
then you could use a query as

```
"SELECT sum(SumofNoOfProjects) as sum_projects, sum(SumofTotalBudgetValue) as sum_value 
    FROM `meed` 
    WHERE Countries IN (" . $_POST['countries'] . ");"
```

Comment: are you sure you have a valid connection  ??  .. i have updated  the asnwer  and added  a check for connection to db too ..  and are you sure your query  return  a valid result

Comment: asnwer  updated  using while  .. the while loop should be executed  if you have at least one valid  row .. are you sure you are looking at the correct php code  ??

Comment: This solution works only if I select one country, but if I select more than one country i get [0,0], what do I need to change on the sql statement so that user can select multiple countries?

Comment: You should  change the query filter for countries  using an `IN` clause instead  of an `=`   and use a proper comma separated  list of values  wrapped  with round brackets..

Comment: do you meen something like this ` "SELECT sum(SumofNoOfProjects) as sum_projects, sum(SumofTotalBudgetValue) as sum_value 
      FROM `meed` 
      WHERE Countries in ('$country')");
`  ?

Comment: yes .. just remember to format the string $countries so as to obtain a valid value eg: `"('Egypt', 'Algerie')"`

Comment: If you don't mind can you show me how to do that by updating your answer?

Comment: @user9964622  answer updated .. with a suggestion ... hope is clear  ,...  and if you don't mind  you could upvote  one  my others answer ..

Comment: Okay but now I get [0,0] and warning `mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in `

Comment: you have not a valid  IN clause  .(query)  .  try var_dump the query you build  ..and check the real content ..

Comment: ` $countries = implode(',',$countries);`
       `var_dump($countries);`   give me this `string(13) "Algeria,Kenya"`

Comment: you need ..   "  'Algeria','Kenya'  "   ...each county name must be enclosed  in quote .. 
 you must build your in clause correctly ..